# IIS without Admin privileges

Tags: iis

I have a login which doesn't have admin privileges, I need to be able to connect to the default web sites available on the same server, if I login to the server with the admin privileges then I am able to see all the websites that are hosted. But if i login with the user which is not running on the admin privileges then none of the websites are visible. Can anyone please suggest what are the privileges that I need to give to the non admin user in order for him to access the websites. I'm using IIS 6.1.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Since you are talking about user and system related permissions you will have better luck looking at http://serverfault.com/